# Fragment.hide() does not hide my Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin

I've implemented the most basic form of `hide()` Fragment and it simply doesn't work.

My initial `onCreate()` adds all 3 fragments to the activity (they all show at the same time). Then when a navigation item is clicked I call `hide()` on 2 fragments - however they don't disappear from the screen - nothing changes.

**My activity:**

```
class TruthOrDare : FragmentActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_truth_or_dare)
        bottomNav_truthordare.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        bottomNav_truthordare.selectedItemId = R.id.action_game
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return
        }
        firstFragment.arguments = intent.extras
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, GameFragment())
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, LeaderboardsFragment())
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, OptionsFragment())
        transaction.commit()

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.hide(GameFragment())
        transaction.hide(OptionsFragment())
        transaction.commit()

        return true
    }
```

**My XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_truthordare"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".TruthOrDare">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_truthordare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:title="Level 1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNav_truthordare" android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_truthordare">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav_truthordare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_items"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_items"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone tell me why `hide()` doesn't work?

Comment: You're trying to hide different instances than the ones that you create and transact in `onCreate()`. Either keep references to the ones you're creating in `onCreate()`, or add tags to their transactions, and use `FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag()` to get them in `onNavigationItemSelected()`.

Comment: Thankyou! `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, GameFragment(), "add_game")` and `val game = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("add_game")` works perfect.